# I'm trying to get country prefix code but this Function passes "code" as null?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my whole code for what i'm trying to do, I have only Write some prefix codes

```
public class CountryToPhonePrefix {

    public static String getPhone(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull final String code) {
        return country2phone.get(code);
    }
    public  Map<String, String> getAll(){
        return country2phone;
    }
    private static Map<String, String> country2phone = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        country2phone.put("AF", "+93");
        country2phone.put("AL", "+355");
        country2phone.put("DZ", "+213");
        country2phone.put("AD", "+376");
        country2phone.put("PS", "+970");
        country2phone.put("EH", "+212");
    }
}
```

Comment: show some code, be more specific, what is each variables defining here...

Comment: @PrajwalW  -    That is my code

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:**

```
public class CountryToPhonePrefix {
Map<String, String> country2phone  //global variable

country2phone = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
country2phone.put("AF", "+93");
        country2phone.put("AL", "+355");
        country2phone.put("DZ", "+213");
        country2phone.put("AD", "+376");
        country2phone.put("PS", "+970");
        country2phone.put("EH", "+212");

public String getPhone(String code)
{
return country2phone.get(code);
}

}
```